# SQL: cte bring back top result each category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

Using SQl server 2008.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refId ORDER BY refid DESC) AS rn
   FROM Products
)
SELECT ProductCategories.Id, 
ProductCategories.Title, 
ProductCategories.languageId, 
ProductCategories.RefId, 
Url
FROM 
 cte
RIGHT JOIN
 RoundupAcademy.dbo.ProductCategories
ON 
 dbo.ProductCategories.RefID = cte.CategoryId
WHERE rn = 1
```

This query should bring back top result of each category
instead it just brings back all results.

i just need the top one based on refid, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that wish to know, the query is fine except the reference for the partition was wrong, it should of been categoryId not refID.

Comment: If this solved your question, mark the answer as accepted so it shows this problem was solved :)